# React filtering information grabbed from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a react container I am working in, and I need to take information stored in an object and filter it and then use it as a variable. Here is where I am at right now:

Please ignore a lot of things I did not filter out, I am aware the way this looks there is a lot of unused variables information being grabbed, it is used in the container.

```
...

componentDidMount() {
  // ... bunch of stuff doing work
  // need to use the categoryId variable inside of here
  // categoryID returns /s/a-12345678 but all I need is the trailing numbers (12345678)
}

DvmContainer.propTypes = {
  categoryId: PropTypes.string
}

const mapStateToProps = function({ config, page, profile }) {
  return {
    categoryId: page.metadata.node_id
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of what the object might look like and what you want it to look like  after being filtered?

Comment: you could do `categoryId = categoryId.split('-')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If your `node_id` is always in that same format, you can use:

```
categoryId: page.metadata.node_id.split('-')[1]
```

in your mapStateToProps.

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression:

```
categoryId: page.metadata.node_id.match(/[0-9]+$/)[0]
```

This matches an uninterrupted string of numbers at the end of the string.

**[Edit]** I would document that with some comments in case you or someone else in the future has to understand why the code is extracting that. In your explanation, focus more on *why* it's being done and not *what* it's doing.

Comment: unfortunately this is close but needed to be limited to match exactly a string of 8 numbers only - other places there could be numbers but I need to extract only when it matches 8 numbers exactly.  Still this was close enough and got me where I needed to go.  Thanks!
This is what I ended up using.
    tcin: page.metadata.seo_data.page_id.match(/\d{8}$/)